# Calculating Timespan in C# and storing result in MSSQL

Tags: c#, datetime-format, timespan

I am trying to calculate the timespan between to sql datetime fields, Bdc_TimeIn (datetime) and Bdc_TimeOut.  I need to store the timespan in a third field called Bdc_TimeElapsed which is currently of Data Type time.

I have tried TimeSpan telapsed = Bdc_TimeOut.Subtract(Bdc_TimeIn); but I get the error:

CS1061  'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Subtract' and no accessible extension method 'Subtract' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

1. How can I calculate the Timespan between Bdc_TimeIn and Bdc_TimeOut
2. How can I store the result in my MSSql Database.

Thanks for any help...Very new to this type of data manipulation.

Comment: Please remember to tag your question with the programming langauge you are using. It greatly improves the chances that users who know that language will notice your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Value` property:

```cs
// Example values.
DateTime? Bdc_TimeOut = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? Bdc_TimeIn = DateTime.Today;

TimeSpan telapsed = Bdc_TimeOut.Value.Subtract(Bdc_TimeIn.Value);
```

The timespan could be stored as a `long`:

```cs
long elapsed = telapsed.Ticks;
```